# how to query the special columns in spark streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

i got a json from kafka in spark streaming,:

```
{"name":"name","value1":"value1"}
{"name":"name","value1":"value1","value2":"value2"}
```

read and get its schema:

```
     val df = spark.read.json(rdd.map(_._2))
     df.printSchema() //shows
      //--name
      //--values1
      // --values2
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
    spark.sql("select name,values2 from df")
```

but it'll output:

> ```
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:77)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:310)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:310)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:309)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:282)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:292)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:296)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
> ```

BTW, its OK in spark but fails in streaming.
anybody know that?

Comment: you can simply do df.select("name", "value2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your code is not correct syntactically so, the **Catalyst optimizer**, while **analyzing** your query, is not able to resolve all references with **Catalog**.

`.json()` method either takes a **path** or **RDD[String]**; not an expression.

Slight change in your code, I guess will resolve this error. Please find below.

**1. Using Spark Sql AST**

It seems you're using AST (as you'registering it as a TempView). Change your code **spark.read.json("select name,values2 from df")** to the following.

```
    spark.sql("select name,values2 from df")
```

**2. Using Spark Sql DSL**

Without creating TempView, you can also achieve the same (I mostly prefer this as the code in DSL is more crisp in nature).

```
 df.select("name","values2")
```

Just skip the code `df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")` in this case and simply call the aforementioned.

Hope, this helps.